# Disable Prelaunch of Microsoft Edge using PowerShell (Unexpected Token)

Tags: windows, powershell, microsoft-edge, prelaunch

I should start off by stressing that I have very, very little experience in PowerShell, so apologies if this is user error.

After copying the commands over from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/browsers/administration/k-12-assessments-reports-apps-background I keep hitting Unexpected Token errors on step 4. This is the code, along with the errors:

$registryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\PreLaunch\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge" $Name = "Enabled" $value = "0" New-Item -Path $registryPath -Force | Out-Null New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null
At line:1 char:138

- ... ch\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge" $Name = "Enab ...
- ```
                                                          ~~~~~
  ```

Unexpected token '$Name' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:156

- ... oftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge" $Name = "Enabled" $value = "0" N ...
- ```
                                                         ~~~~~~
  ```

Unexpected token '$value' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:169

- ... d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge" $Name = "Enabled" $value = "0" New-Item -Path $ ...
- ```
                                                       ~~~~~~~~
  ```

Unexpected token 'New-Item' in expression or statement.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

I've tried messing around with a few things and have gotten rid of some, but not all of the errors. Any help would be greatly appreacited!

Answer (score 2):

Sample formatting on that documentation article is broken, it's hiding a couple of linebreaks:

```
$registryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\PreLaunch\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge"
$Name = "Enabled"
$value = "0"
New-Item -Path $registryPath -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null
```